# Magento 2 : UpgradeSchema write mysql trigger

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, upgradeschema, mysql-triggers

I am trying to add mysql trigger using the upgradeschema in magento 2 but I am getting the "Cannot execute multiple queries". Below is my trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER customerdata_insert_before 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON customerdata
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.longitude IS NULL) THEN
  SET NEW.longitude = `00.000000`;
END IF;
IF (NEW.latitude IS NULL) THEN
  SET NEW.latitude = `00.000000`;
END IF;
  SET NEW.geo_point = Point(NEW.latitude, NEW.longitude);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Please Help.